# android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.getDisplays() is not returning the external monitor connected to chromebook

Tags: android, chromebook

I am working on Acer Chromebook R11. The Android version of Chromebook is 7.1.1. The external monitor is connected via HDMI port on Chromebook. OS is showing both the displays and am able to drag the apps from one window to another window.

I want my app to display on both the screens. While querying for the displays, android display manager is returning only the default display information. The external monitor information is not present with the displaymanager.

```
 import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
 ..
 ..
DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    Display[] var1 = displayManager.getDisplays();
Display[] var2 = displayManager.getDisplays( DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
```

var1 is always having the default built-in screen information. I am expecting it to have information about the two displays. 
var2 is always null.

Is there any issue with this API on Chromebook?

Comment: From docs: `getDisplays() Gets all currently valid logical displays.` From that point `getDisplays(category)` seems redundant. How many displays are in `var1` array?

Comment: @ Eugen Pechanec , Var1 has 1 display that is built-in display. Agree Var2 is redundant, but just added there to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This api is working after I updated the OS on chromebook via beta channel.